# Module 'flutter_facebook_login' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook-login

I'm using the [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login#flutter_facebook_login) package and I got this error message:

*"Module 'flutter_facebook_login' not found"*

in the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m file in iOS.

is there anyone faced this issue? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same problem. I just deleted Podfile, Podfile.lock and Pods folder, installed flutter_facebook_login again (latest version) and did "flutter pub get". It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you are using `Runner.xcworkspace` and not `Runner.xcodeproj`

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41033#issuecomment-534604875

Answer (score 0):

I updated the plugin to the version in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

then updated the podfile in ios folder

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.5'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.5'
```

at the end rebuild everything, message gone.

Answer (score 0):

for me, i had to update the xcode ios deployment target settings to match flutter Podfile 'platform: ios' setting. details at following link, answer posted by @thanhbinh84 :

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode)