# Flutter shared_preferences module not found - iOS Xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am using `shared_preferences` dependency in Flutter.

Building Xcode (Product->archive - for Generic target) fails with

```
module 'shared_preferences' not found
```

[image: Build in Xcode fails]

I tried `flutter clean`, `flutter pub cache repair`, tried moving Flutter lib/ into new project (`flutter create .`) and I building using older Xcode version (11.4.1)..currently I have 12.0 beta 3.

What is weird is that running in Emulator from my IDE (IntelliJ) works just fine with no errors.

[image: IDE Emulator dart main runs OK]

These are my dependencies (pubspec.yaml)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  intl: any
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  redux: any
  flutter_redux: any
  redux_thunk: any
  shared_preferences: 0.5.1+2
```

Comment: Did you do run `flutter build ios` to create a release build? See: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive

Comment: Yes I did, but thank you for that doc link, I read it before but now I noticed that I was opening Project.xcodeproj instead of Project.xcworkspace in Xcode. Builds just fine now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my case problem was that I was opening Xcode project from Project.xcodeproj instead of Project.xcworkspace.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the scheme in the following manner:

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Searching on Stack Overflow I found this
[Flutter module not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode/65418772)
Which links to this
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54599#issuecomment-644336055

This solved it for me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using project scheme mode as debug then change your scheme to release from debug.

product -> scheme -> debug to release.

and again try to archive project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue aswell with flutter upgrading xcode and flutter 2.12.

to fix this:

1. inside ios folder, delete all folders and files, keep the ios folder in your flutter project.
2. within the flutter project execute > flutter create .
3. open the ios/Runner.xworkspace with xcode
4. within xcode, there will be a yellow alert icon top right, click that and fix the suggested issues.
5. build with xcode

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the ios folder, then i ran in the project path:

```
flutter create .
flutter build ios
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete podfile.lock & pods folder & derived data
2. 'pod install' again
3. Clean & build

That should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

**To anyone who is coming here in 2022 with a Mac M1**

Please try

1. flutter clean
2. cd ios/
3. arch -x86_64 pod install

that fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles over this problem while using Fastlane: the solution "open Project.xcodeproj instead of Project.xcworkspace" also applies to that case!

In your `Fastfile`, build the app like this:

```rb
build_app(
  workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
  # ...
)
```

NOT like this:

```rb
build_app(
  project: "Runner.xcodeproj", # BAD IDEA!
  # ...
)
```

Otherwise, Cocoapods dependencies are not correctly referenced. Cost me a while to figure that out ...

Answer (score 0):

I replace the `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file by a new flutter project’s ios floder. that work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this command

pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install