# 'cloud_firestore' not found

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I believe I've had this problem before and it was solved by changing my Podfile to this:

(ios is the same in xcode, if that's relevant)

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
          pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/full-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      else
          pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

and ran `pod install`

Here's where my GoogleServices-info.plist file is:

[image: GoogleServices-info.plist]

[image: pubspec.yaml]

I did pub upgrade and pub get

I also deleted Podfile.lock and ran `pod install`

Do I need to change something in my Podfile? Or is the problem elsewhere?

It was working before I made changes in my android folder/gradle files. Could that have affected it?

Answer (score 0):

Followed answer from here [Flutter module not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode/65418772)

1.- Delete Podfile

In Android Studio:

2.- flutter clean

3.- flutter pub get

4.- cd ios

5.- pod install

An then

6.- Build and run your app through Xcode

After that didn't work for me, in Xcode I went to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and beside Build Option I checked Find Implicit Dependencies. Works fine now. Had to let it run its course with it checked in android studio and now it works without it checked.