# Module 'flutter_barcode_scanner' not found [Flutter / iOS]

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to run a Flutter app on iOS device after some time but the project is failing to build for iOS.

The error that I am getting is happening in the "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h" file and  is as follows:

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<flutter_barcode_scanner/SwiftFlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_barcode_scanner/SwiftFlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_barcode_scanner; /* ERROR: Module 'flutter_barcode_scanner' not found */
#endif
```

My pubspec.yaml content are as follows:

```
name: test_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.2.0
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/playstore_icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 29

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/illustrations/
```

There is no issue with my Flutter as outputted by **flutter doctor** *command* as follows:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

To resolve the issue I tried the following commands first:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

But the issue still persisted. Then I used the following steps to resolve the issue:

Step 1: Deleted the iOS folder in the project.

Step 2: Used the commands in terminal as follows -

```
flutter create -i swift .
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

The issue still persisted and the build failed with the same error as above.

Not quite sure now how to resolve this. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do as instruction in pub.dev? Set ios deployment target to 12 and set Swift version to 5. Then close XCode, go inside ios folder (terminal) & run `pod install`...

Answer (score 0):

For me, this answer was helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68299585/20274645

After that run:

- `pod install` in the **`ios`** folder
- `flutter build ios`

---

For the "flutter_barcode_scanner" package, generally note that the ios deployment target must be set to at least 12 and the Swift version must be set to at least 5.