# Module 'device_info_plus' not found in flutter iOS build

Tags: flutter

I am doing a flutter iOS build in Xcode using a flutter setup for which android build is done. I have added the iOS platform and when I open "Runner.xcworkspace" in Xcode and run it i am getting module not found error like "Module 'device_info_plus' not found".

I tried different solutions suggested by others in [Flutter module not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode) but still my issue is not resolved.

Comment: I am using Apple M1

Answer (score 0):

in your podfile change  platform:ios, '12.0'