# GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9 Module 'better_player' not found. ,using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Hi I am trying to build my flutter project in xcode ,

[image]

I tried all of the following but nothing worker:

[Flutter module not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode)

GitHub
https://github.com › flutter › flutter › issues

GitHub
https://github.com › flutter › flutter › issues

all of the following were of no use :

1- opening the Runner.xcworkspace instead of the Runner.xcodeproject.

2-cleaning the flutter  project ,the pod and the ios directory.

3-setting the deployment ios version and matching the pod file with  xcode.

thanks in advance