# How to write "Podfile" in flutter(ios)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, macos, podfile

First code I use the Podfile below

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
  use_frameworks!
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
      'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
  end
end
```

And then 'pod install'. The result message is 'Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 pods installed'
Suspicious thing is that 0 pods installed and also when I build in XCode, error is occured

Second code(Podfile) I try below

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
      'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
  end
end
```

This doesn't work either.
The error below is occured in Xcode.

```
Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
Module {{import package thing..}} not found
```

This is occured in GeneratedPluginRegistrant file

As a result, what I want to ask is, first Podfile is suspicious because of '0 pods installed' message so is there any problem in my Podfile?
Second is Xcode error message that is occured in GeneratedPluginRegistrant file. I think this error is related to Podfile but I can't convince that is really related

Thank you for read this question.

- In MAC OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by referencing other question/answer ->
[Flutter module not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956166/flutter-module-not-found-in-xcode)

Below is the method which is useful!

First

1. Delete Podfile
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. flutter build ios

Second, make sure platform: iOS version in pod file matches with deployment info in Xcode

Third, if you run the program through Xcode, you have to opened the Runner.xcworkspace file in XCode, not Runner.xcodeproj file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe theres a typo in the Podfile.. PERMISSION_CARMERA should be PERMISSION_CAMERA? I only know swift so forgive me if I am wrong. Maybe that is part of the solution?

Comment: Actually, there are no typo in my code, just typo in my question. So I modified my question. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Welcome. Wish I could be of more assistance. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove 'RunnerTests'

For examlme,

As-is

```html
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

Tobe

```html
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Comment: Remove 'RunnerTests' is also needed, but main method that I solved is regenerate Podfile by flutter command, not "pod init".
Thank you for answering, and have a nice day !